# Redirect to previous page after action controller

Tags: php, symfony, redirect

I'd like to do redirect to previous page after action controller but I get this error.
**Symfony version 2.5.8**

```
Cannot redirect to an empty URL.
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException
```

This is the actiuon:

```
    public function addFavoriteAction(Travel $travel, Request $request)
    {

    if (!$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('fos_user_security_login'));
    }

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'GET') {

    $favorite = new Favorite();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $favorite->setUser($this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser());
    $favorite->setTravel($travel);


    $em->persist($favorite);
    $em->flush();
    }

    $referer = $this->getRequest()->headers->get('referer');
    return $this->redirect($referer);
}
```

**UPDATED**

**The error comes because I typed the link of action directly into the browser address bar.**

Answer (score 6):

Solutions with referer is not reliable, it was be `null`. Proxy, browsers may be cut it. You need check `$referer` variable at first.

```
    $referer = $this->getRequest()->headers->get('referer');
    if ($referer == NULL) {
        $url = $this->router->generate('fallback_url');
    } else {
        $url = $referer;
    }
```